# NextJS/Link component href error in production

Tags: next.js

Let's say I've this folder structure:

> pages/index.js

> pages/contact/index.js

with **pages/index.js** having this link:

```
<Link href='/contact'>Contact me</a>
```

If I run the production build locally:

```
yarn build
yarn start
```

(yarn build comand: `next build && next export`, cause I want to self-host it as a static html website)

Link works fine. But if I move that on my production machine, and I click the Link, I get a 404 error, which I can manually work around adding '.html' at the end of the url in the address bar:

/contact -> /contact.html

which is pretty obvious due to the build structure, **that flats all the *pages/folder* in root renaming the index.js file with its floder name**. Nonetheless, it works fine on my machine.

If I change the href to /contact.html, it works fine in production, but get broken locally.

So I believe there is some mismatch between my local server and the production one. What can I do to have the same build working on both machine?

Comment: Is'it deployed on Vercel? This is more likely a problem with how your server is configured, not a Next.js' issue.

Comment: @yousoumar no, it's self hosted as a static html website buid with next build && next export comand

Comment: I think this can help: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths